# Is there a Python library to do constrained triangulations in 3D?

Tags: python, triangulation, delaunay

I have a function whose range is a non-convex, simply connected region in R3. When I sample the function I know if the resulting point is on the surface of the region or not. I'd like to triangulate those samples subject to the surface constrains, i.e., the resulting tetrahedra should not 
"hide" surface points. The hull would not be convex, of course.

I searched around for a library. So far I found Triangle, but it only works in R2. I also found TetGen, which works in R3, but it requires to provide
the surface triangulation (which I don't have). Also, as far as I can see, these C/C++ libraries do not have Python bindings.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Someone may object to this question on SO, on the grounds that it's not about programming *per se*. In case you don't know about the sites, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and https://www.quora.com/ might offer you more useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org) it has [python-bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cgal-bindings).

One side note: If you need the surface triangulation (which seems to be a 2D problem), you may take each face, project it to 2D, triangulate it, and back to your 3D face.

EDIT due to comment: CGAL does "only" [3D triangulation](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/index.html). 3D constrained triangulation requires Steiner points. Since not every input can be triangulated in 3D ([Schönhardt polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron) as the classical counter-example).

Maybe you can take a look at [MeshPy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MeshPy) it looks like it has what you are looking for: "MeshPy provides Python interfaces to three well-regarded mesh generators, Triangle by J. Shewchuk, TetGen by Hang Si, and gmsh by Christophe Geuzaine and Jean-Francois Remacle."

Comment: Thank you. I do need the 3D triangulation.

Comment: @Eduardo Ok, I may have found what you are looking for in MeshPy (added it to my answer).